# C++ indexed access to structure variables of different types

Tags: c++, data-structures, structure

I have a number of bool and int variables, that I need to access by some sort of index. I found a way to do so, but it seems a bit too complicated. Is there a way to do this in more elegant way?

For now in header file I have structure

```
struct FDialogueFlags
{
    bool tmpFlag1;
    bool tmpFlag2;
    // bool tmpFlagX;

    int tmpState1;
    int tmpState2;
    // int tmpStateX;
};
```

and enumeration

```
enum class Eflags
{
    // NAME = flag_ID,

    TMP_FLAG_1 = 1,         
    TMP_FLAG_2 = 10,                
    // TMP_FLAG_X = XX,

    TMP_STATE_1 = 101,              
    TMP_STATE_2 = 110,          
    // TMP_STATE_X = XXX,
};
```

And in source file I have function, that returns values for given index - flag_ID

```
int GetFlagValue(int flag_ID)
{
    switch (Eflags(flag_ID))
    {
    case (Eflags::TMP_FLAG_1):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpFlag1;
        break;
    case (Eflags::TMP_FLAG_2):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpFlag2;
        break;
    /*case (Eflags::TMP_FLAG_X):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpFlagX;
        break;*/
    case (Eflags::TMP_STATE_1):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpState1;
        break;
    case (Eflags::TMP_STATE_2):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpState2;
        break;
    /*case (Eflags::TMP_STATE_X):
        return flagsAndStates.tmpStateX;
        break;*/
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

That way everytime I need to add new "flag" or "state" I have to edit 3 places in my code.

Besides, if I need to access any "flag" or "state" by it's name written in enum, I can not do so, because `Eflags (TMP_FLAG_1)` returns `TMP_FLAG_1` and not a number.
The other important thing, I'd like to keep variable namings, there might be up to hundred of this "flags" and "states" and it's crusial for them to have unique names and not just iterative numbers (Code above is just an example, in the end product I would name all of them according to their meaning) 
If possible I'd like to avoid using `std::map` since it isn't supported natively by UE4.
So, the core idea is to access certain amount of variables of different numeric types by given number, possibly keeping variable naming.

Comment: why do you need to access them index wise? constant time access or syntactic sugar?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a vector of ints and a vector of bools?

Comment: well if these are going to be only bools and integers and assuming the number and duplication is quite low, you can just use array of integers.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I have XML file wich containes nodes with numeric flag IDs. I can change numbers to strings but that wouldn't be that different. I still would have to search for flag by given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are asking for syntactic alternatives, Can you use tuples? Here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple

They are similar to structures and you can use [std::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to retrieve values with index-based method. You can then use if statements for comparisons instead of switch statement.

Example -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple(1, true, 25);

    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << "\n"
              << std::get<1>(t) << "\n"
              << std::get<2>(t) << "\n";
}
```

[**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/0Wg23i)

---

I don't have any experience with UE4 and what native support means, but there are numerous drop-in alternatives to std::map like this [one](https://github.com/greg7mdp/sparsepp).

Comment: Thanks that look very promising. I could actually make cycle to search for tuple with specific field content.

Comment: UE4 has pretty limited supported variables, but it doesn't mean I can't use anything I want, it just means that I wouldn't be able to access unsupported variables inside editor, only in code. But that's ok, I think I can make accessor functions